# Best way to get arguments from string by user for chat bot

Tags: arrays, string, discord, chatbot, discord.js

I need to accept 2 arguments: first is time argument for example "1m", "2h 42m", "1d 23h 3s", second is text. I thought I can just convert input string to array and split it into 2 array using regex maybe, first with "d", "h", "m" and "s", second everything else and convert in back to string. but then I realize I'll need 3rd argument which gonna be optional target channel (dm or current channel, where command been executed), and also what if user want to include 1m in his text (it's reminder command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to have the user seperate each argument by a comma. Although this creates the issue where the user can't user a comma in their text part. So if that isn't an option, another way to do it is to get the message content and start by stripping parts of it away. You begin by grabbing the time portion with a regex. Then you look for channel mentions and strip those away. What you're left with should solely be the text.

Below is some (non-tested) code which could lead you in the right direction. Give it a try and let me know if you have any problems

```js
let msg = {
  content: "1d 3h 45m 52s I feel like 4h would be to long <#222079895583457280>",
  mentions: {
    channels: ['<#222079895583457280>']
  }
};

// Mocked Message object for testing purpose
let messageObject = {
  mentions: {
    CHANNELS_PATTERN: /<#([0-9]+)>/g
  }
}


function handleCommand (message) {
  let content = message.content;
  
  let timeParts = content.match(/^(([0-9])+[dhms] )+/g);
  let timePart = '';
  
  if (timeParts.length) {
    // Get only the first match. We don't care about others
    timePart = timeParts[0];
    
    // Removes the time part from the content
    content = content.replace(timePart, '');
  }
  
  // Get all the (possible) channel mentions
  let channels = message.mentions.channels;
  let channel = undefined;
  
  // Check if there have been channel mentions
  if (channels.length) {
    channel = channels[0];
    
    // Remove each channel mention from the message content
    let channelMentions = content.match(messageObject.mentions.CHANNELS_PATTERN);
    
    channelMentions.forEach((mention) => {
      content = content.replace(mention, '');
    })
  }
  
  console.log('Timepart:', timePart);
  console.log('Channel:', channel, '(Using Discord JS this will return a valid channel to do stuff with)');
  console.log('Remaining text:', content);
}

handleCommand(msg);
```

For the `messageObject.mentions.CHANNEL_PATTERN` look at [this reference](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=s-CHANNELS_PATTERN)